# Relying on 'disconnect' event in socket.io/express.io when using Angular's single-page app engine

Tags: node.js, sockets, angularjs, express, socket.io

How is it possible to add a 'disconnect' event whenever I leave a page that is intercepted by my single page application engine?

I have certain events set up (kind of like streaming events on YouTube) and each requires its own socket connection. I now set up a single-page engine on Angular that allows switching between these events.

I used to rely on the 'disconnect' event to let me know when someone has left the event, but they don't work anymore - the socket never shuts off if I leave via my single-page navigation.

Is there any way to configure the socket to still disconnect?

My less-than-ideal approach was to create a new instance of the socket connection on a controller of every page to which I can navigate from the event page, and forbid multiple connections.

If anybody has a better idea, I would love to hear it.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You may call it manually since you are in control of page navigation - whenever client is navigating away from one page, call

```
socket.disconnect();
socket.close();
```

This will ensure that when client is navigating away from one page the socket gets disconnected before that.